# Animating a Pseudo Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to achieve a particular effect `onclick`.  I've created an angled or razor-blade style `div` using a parent `div-element`, and a pseudo-element `:after` (see snippet below).  What I'm trying to make happen is when the user clicks on the parent element, the skew property I have set up, shifts to a different skewed angle.

My problem is what regardless of whether I call the parent or the pseudo, `onclick` I cannot get the animation to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $('.slantedDiv').click(function() {
  $('.slantedDiv .slantedDiv:after').toggleClass('active');
 });
});
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.slantedDiv {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: yellow;
}

.slantedDiv:after {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 content: '';
 background: inherit;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 transform-origin: top left;
 transform: skewY(10deg);
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.active {
 transform-origin: top right;
 transform: skewY(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slantedDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks for the post reference.  I've made the edit from element to class as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is to do with the selector in the `click` handler. Firstly, the element is just `.slantedDiv`, so repeating the class will not match any elements. You can avoid that issue entirely by just using the `this` reference in the jQuery object. Secondly, and more importantly, jQuery cannot select pseudo elements so including `:after` will not find anything.

Instead you need to `toggle()` the `active`class on the `.slantedtDiv` directly and then use the `:after` in your CSS rule based on the presence of the `active` class, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slantedDiv').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.slantedDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.slantedDiv:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  background: inherit;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: skewY(10deg);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.slantedDiv.active:after {
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slantedDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Will mark correct when timer runs out